# swift userdefaults settings testing value

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, string

I need to test if the settings page has been completed when the app starts.
What should I test for? This is what I tried but get an error unwrapping.
The value is a string.
I tried using ObjectForKey and tested for nil but same issue.
I am new to this so Thanks for any help.

```
let settingtest:String = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("bankid")!
    if (settingtest.isEmpty) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("getsettings", sender: self)
    }
```

This works for iPad Air but fails on iPad Retina (both simulators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let settingTest = "questar"
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(settingTest, forKey: "Myid")
```

You can use if let to safely unwrap your value:

```
if let loadedSettingTest = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Myid") {
    println(loadedSettingTest)  // "questar"
} else {
   println("empty")
}
```

or you can use the nil coalescing operator "??" to return an empty String in case of user defaults returns nil:

```
var loadedSettingTest = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Myid") ?? ""

if loadedSettingTest.isEmpty {
   println(true)
} else {
    println(false)  // false
}


NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey("Myid")

loadedSettingTest = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Myid") ?? ""

if loadedSettingTest.isEmpty {
    println(true)    // true
} else {
    println(false)
}
```

Comment: Using your first fix it works OK on iPad Air but fails on iPad retina and iPhone 6. I don't change the OS version so why work on one but not the other? Still simulated.

Comment: It doesn't return the error but the test fails on iPhone6 and iPad Retina. It doesn't fail on iPad Air or iPhone 5s.

Comment: @questar this should work on all devices. I can also test it here for you when I get a chance using the simulator and let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: The coalescing operator "??" solution works for all. Thanks for your help. I learned something today.